# Title not showing in bibliography due to modification of .bst file

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have modified the `eprint` entry in the `hsiam.bst` bibliography style file from arXiv (available [here](https://arxiv.org/help/hypertex/bibstyles/)). More specifically, I have substituted the `format.eprint` function for the following one:

```
FUNCTION {format.eprint}
{ eprint empty$
    { "" }
    { "available in \href{https://arxiv.org/abs/" eprint * "}{arXiv:" eprint * "}" *}
  if$
}
```

When I cite the following entry

```
@Article{testone,
  Title                    = {Sample Title},
  Author                   = {Me Myself},

  Month                    = {August},

  Eprint                   = {2222.2222},
  Url                      = {https://arxiv.org/abs/2222.2222}
}
```

in an MWE like the following:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{article}
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{hsiam}

\begin{document}
\nobibliography{biblio}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \bibentry{testone}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error when compiling with Bibtex:

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux The style file: hsiam.bst Database file #1: publications.bib Warning--empty journal in testone Warning--empty year in testone ptr=1, stack= {\em Sample Title} ---the literal stack isn't empty for entry testone while executing---line 1053 of file hsiam.bst (There was 1 error message)

My guess is that I am calling `eprint` twice, but I don't know any other way to get the desired result, which should be like this:

> M. Myself, *Sample Title*, available in [arXiv:2222.2222](https://arxiv.org/abs/2222.2222), 2015.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is it a good idea to assign the entry type `@article` to pieces not published in a formal journal? For sure, the fields `journal` and `year` are *required* for entries of type `@article`.

Comment: When I add a `journal` field, the title appears but the year disappears, it looks like it's kind of trying to fit the pieces of information in not enough boxes.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would provide us with the means to reproduce the issue. To do this, I suggest adding the change you have made to the `.bst` file in the form of a standard patch. We also need a small, complete document which, when copy-paste-compiled reproduces the error you are having trouble with. On a unix-type system, you can produce a standard patch file using `diff -Naur <path to original/siam.bst> <path to new/siam2.bst>`, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately I do not have access now to a unix-type system, but all the modifications done are explained in the post. I have also created an MWE in which I already find the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the solution I have found is to add a `*` before the second `eprint` call, having the following code:

```
FUNCTION {format.eprint}
{ eprint empty$
    { "" }
    { "available in \href{http://arxiv.org/abs/" eprint * "}{arXiv: " * eprint * "}" *}
  if$
}
```

When compiling the previous MWE, now the output of BibTeX is

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux The style file: hsiam.bst Database file #1: biblio.bib

No errors at all, as looked for.

Thank you all for your help!